# Como fazer um dcast( função do R para pivotar uma tabela) no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

Estou iniciando no estudo do SQl, antes eu trabalhava com R. E gostaria de saber como realizar no SQL, algo semelhante a função dcast do R. Na função dcast eu consigo pivotar uma tabela, selecionando as variáveis eu quero que continue como estão, quais eu quero que os valores vire colunas e qual variavel eu quero que vire os valores dessas colunas novas, segue um exemplo da função:

A base veio assim:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOcaa.jpg)

Então eu aplico a função dcast:

```
 media_percentual_acertos <- dcast(
      data = t1,
      formula = NM_ESCOLA + id_etapa ~ id_disciplina,
      value.var = "media_percentual_acertos"
    )
```

E a base passa a ser assim:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPdXs.jpg)

Gostaria de saber como fazer a mesma coisa do SQL?

Comment: PIVOT ... https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso, eu precisava da média como valor. Mas você pode somar, contar e etc.

```
PIVOT
(
AVG(percentual_acertos)
FOR id_disciplina IN ('Língua Inglesa', 'Química', 'Filosofia', 'Matemática', 'Física', 'Biologia', 'Língua Portuguesa', 'História','Sociologia','Geografia')

)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).